# Excel 2007 upgrade error

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, excel

In a Windows Forms application I'm saving some data to an Excel file.
Until now, i was using Excel 2003 and saving as the file as xls. with this code :

```
exportFile.SaveAs(strPath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

I've upgraded to Excel 2007 and now I want to save the data as xlsx, so i've changed the same line to :

```
exportFile.SaveAs(strPath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

But now, i get an exception on that line , "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"
Do you have any idea what am i doing wrong ?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you reference the new interop assemblies from Excel 2007?

Comment: Yes, I've deleted the old 2003 refference and added the 2007

Comment: What is `XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared` all about? What happens if you use `Type.Missing` or `xlNoChange` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried @david heffernan's solution and worked.
XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange did the trick